# DataGridView Tap function "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datagridview, devexpress

I'm developing xamarin forms app and I make a query page. User select paremeters here and work queries. But I got this error when I take apk from visual studio and run on the phone. It's working well, while working on debug mode on emulator. I can't figure out what's wrong with that.

Devexpress datagridview generated auto because I use dynmaic object here. It has to be dynamic because we change query and use the same page for this select process.

```
 private async void dataTable_Tap(object sender, DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var menuItem = (DevExpress.XamarinForms.DataGrid.DataGridView)sender;
            if (menuItem != null)
            {
                if (e != null)
                {
                    dynamic dItem = e.Item;
                    if (dItem != null)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(dItem[0]);
                        //Console.WriteLine(e.Item.ToString());
                        //Console.WriteLine(dItem[vNumber]);
                        string queryParameter = Preferences.Get("queryParameters", "");
                        queryParameter += dItem[vNumber] + pid + ";;";
                        Preferences.Set("queryParameters", queryParameter);
                        Console.WriteLine(queryParameter);
                        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
                        DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().UzunMesaj($"{dItem[vNumber]}");
                    }

                    
                }
            }


        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("", $"Can not select : \n{ex.Message}", "Tmm");
            throw;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed problem.**

I changed the declaration

Before:

> dynamic dItem = e.Item;

After:

> var dataRow = e.Item as DataRow;

Comment: 1. I can reproduce the issue, to fix it, you need to cast the `e.Item` to `DataRow`. 2. Glad you solved it, you can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.

Comment: Thank you Alexandar May for your advice. I'll accept my answer tomorrow.